# Angular. Value from Event on MatSelectionListChange is undefined

Tags: angular, events, angular-material

I'm trying to get a value of a changed element in a list, but I'm getting always *value* undefined while the property *checked* is right.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <mat-selection-list #costUnits
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCostUnits"
    (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
    >
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let label of labels" selected="true">
            {{ label }}
        </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
  onSelectionChange(event: MatSelectionListChange) {
    console.log(event)
  }
```

For example:
I've clicked twice on one element in the list that was checked and got the following outputs.

[image: console.log output]

Comment: are you able to see the contents of labels array on UI???

Comment: Yes. I'm affected by the problem only in the listener. @ShlokNangia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. The value wasn't bound. The right code of the component is it:

```
<mat-list-option 
  *ngFor="let label of labels" 
  selected="true" 
  [value]="label"
  >
    {{ label }}
</mat-list-option>
```

Comment: Note that option is deprecated.  Use event.options[0].value if [multiple]="false.